# How do you await long running process from ASPNET CORE SignalR Hub

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I have an application flow where:

1. Clientside Javascript triggers signalR Hub
2. Asynchronous Call is made
   for long running operation
3. When operation is complete Clientside JavaScript is notified by signalR

I had assumed this would be as simple as:

Server Side:

```
public async void SendMessage()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage");
}
```

Client Side:

```
var hub = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl('/disposeBugHub').build();

this.hub.on("ReceiveMessage", function () {
    alert('Message Received');
});

this.hub.start()
    .then(function () {
        hub.invoke("SendMessage");
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
```

However the Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage"); call always throws a System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.' Exception.

This appears to be expected behavoir and not a bug, so my question is how do i programmatically acheive the desired workflow? I assume there must be a well known pattern to acheive this but I cant find it online.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , remove `void` method for long running process. use `Task` return type method .

Try this.

```
        public async Task SendMessage()
        {
            await Task.Delay(10000);
            Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage");
        }
```